# How do I fix a stripped hole in a vinyl casement window?

Tags: vinyl, hole-repair

While replacing my window crank with a T-crank I noticed the screw that is holding the gear box in place didn't seem to be doing it's job.  Upon further inspection it seems that it's stripped out.

**How do I fix a stripped hole in vinyl?**  Can I just use toothpicks and wood glue like I normally would?

Comment: Try a bigger screw

Comment: Or a longer screw and try to anchor to the framework without affecting the gear box.

Comment: @Alaskaman, the thread is already at the max width for the hardware.

Comment: @EdBeal I'd need a significantly longer screw, but it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned a longer screw in my comment, I need to expand on this. A longer screw of the same size may need to be inches longer to contact wood framing because of shims. But a longer screw that engages with framing will not affect the gear box functions. A larger screw as some suggest may affect the gear box. I have used longer screws on high precision gear boxes that worked as well or better than the original that stripped out. But going larger may cause offset or problems with the gears in simple from the larger head and or shaft.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  This made sense to me so I tried it, but was having trouble setting a longer screw, so I opened my window (I've been reluctant to do so because it's sub-freezing outside) and noticed that this isn't going to work for me.  Updating my question with some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Can you force a plastic anchor into the hole and then drive in the screw? You might have to enlarge the hole to fit an anchor of the right size, but I would first try to do it without enlarging the hole.

**EDIT** I assumed the screw you mentioned would be one which held the opening mechanism to either the window or to the frame. Is the screw one which is part of the mechanism, in effect a helical gear? If that is worn, you might have to replace the entire mechanism for that window.

Comment: As the anchor is also plastic, won't it just spin? or won't I'll have to notch the anti-spin channels?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of a different type of plastic anchor than you.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: This type comes in different sizes: https://www.zoro.com/gardner-bender-plastic-conical-anchor-14-x-1-pk100-ap4-k100/i/G6928588/feature-product?gclid=Cj0KCQiAgMPgBRDDARIsAOh3uyKgd8GXqq3Y_xOZKku8NswW3GrnBn1EaKb9NHcS3J1yyplUO9-XVo8aAkXUEALw_wcB

Comment: I was able to find one of those in my girlfriend's junk drawer.  Unfortunately the lip on the head is too tall and throws my gearbox out of alignment.

Comment: Cut off the small end by enough to that the flange of the anchor rests on the surface.